# Uniform Cost search project euler #81

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, uniform

I am working on project euler programs for the sake of 'enlightenment' not just solving them. I have solved question 81 using dynamic progam on the 80x80 matrix but when I try to solve it using uniform cost search my program disappears into never land. I just want to know if this problem tractable using uniform cost search? The problem is available at [this link](http://projecteuler.net/problem=81).

Comment: I feel like it should be solvable with UCS... what happened when you tried it? Did it time out?

Comment: It worked on the smaller problem but on the 80x80 matrix, it just goes on till the fan of the laptop comes on..

Comment: I just did it in ~15 lines of Python with UCS and got it correct. I think you're forgetting something in your algorithm. (Did you check to make sure you're not re-examining the same node twice? It's not that different from DP.)

Comment: will love over my algo once more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UCS definitely works.

```py
from Queue import PriorityQueue
with open('matrix.txt') as f:
    data = map(lambda s: map(int, s.strip().split(',')), f.readlines())
seen = set()
pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.put((data[0][0], 0, 0))
while not pq.empty():
    (s, i, j) = pq.get()
    if (i, j) not in seen:
        seen.add((i, j))
        if i + 1 < len(data):    pq.put((s + data[i + 1][j], i + 1, j))
        if j + 1 < len(data[i]): pq.put((s + data[i][j + 1], i, j + 1))
        if i + 1 >= len(data) and j + 1 >= len(data): print s
```

Comment: finally made it work..the problem was not the algorithm but the data structures. Was using a list for my priority queue and closed set so I am guessing it was causing the algo to take forever. Thanks for the answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here (as a reference) is a solution using [Uniform-cost search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search) in c++, compiled with `-O2` takes less than a second on a i7 (without optimizations takes 3 secs):

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct Node { 
    size_t i, j; int cost;
    Node(size_t i, size_t j, int cost) : i(i), j(j), cost(cost) {}
};
bool operator<(const Node& a, const Node& b) { return b.cost < a.cost; }
bool operator==(const Node& a, const Node& b) { return a.i == b.i && a.j == b.j; }

int main() {
    const size_t SIZE = 80;
    ifstream fis("matrix.txt");
    int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    char crap;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            fis >> matrix[i][j];
            if (j < SIZE - 1) fis >> crap;
        }
    vector<Node> open;
    set<Node> closed;
    open.push_back(Node(0, 0, matrix[0][0]));
    make_heap(open.begin(), open.end());
    while (!open.empty()) {
        Node node = open.front();
        pop_heap(open.begin(), open.end()); open.pop_back();

        if (node.i == SIZE - 1 && node.j == SIZE - 1) {
            cout << "solution " << node.cost << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        closed.insert(node);
        Node children[] = { Node(node.i + 1, node.j, node.cost + matrix[node.i + 1][node.j]),
                            Node(node.i, node.j + 1, node.cost + matrix[node.i][node.j + 1]) };
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) { 
            Node child = children[k];
            if (!closed.count(child)) {
                vector<Node>::iterator elem = find(open.begin(), open.end(), child);
                if (elem == open.end()) { 
                    open.push_back(child); push_heap(open.begin(), open.end());
                } else if (child.cost < (*elem).cost) {
                    (*elem).cost = child.cost;
                    make_heap(open.begin(), open.end());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution would be little slow because it calls `make_heap` for element replacement in the open node list which rebuilds the heap in the vector, but shouldn't go to forever land and proves that the problem can be solved with UCS. A suggestion is to debug your solution using the base case given in Project Euler problem statement.

Comment: Why would UCS be slower than DP? Or to put it another way... what specific DP algorithm are you referring to? Bellman-Ford, or something else?

Comment: Hmm, 80×80 are 6400 elements. That shouldn't take more than a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, but I'm calling `make_heap` after element replacement in the open list and used a `set` instead of a `map` for explored nodes, just to make the answer shorter as possible (I think it can shortened though). This code can be improved but is just a reference that proves the problem could be solved using UCS

Comment: @Mehrdad Sorry, I was talking about my implementation of the UCS, not about the general case, my bad (this answer make use of `make_heap` for element replace in open list which rebuilds the heap in the vector, is not optimal but proves the problem could be solved with UCS)

Comment: Yes, with a real PQ, that would be much faster already. But the bookkeeping overhead with the queue is so large that I doubt it would be as fast as a simple BFS (that would change for problems 82 and 83).